# laravel one to Many Relationship with multiple table, query not optimized?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a table call table1(i am using some pretended name for tables here) like follow

```
id_table1    description
```

And Model  is Like 
`

```
class Table1 extends \Eloquent {
  public $timestamps = false;
  protected $table = 'table1';
  protected $fillable = [ 'description'];

  protected $primaryKey = 'id_table1';

  public function relation5s(){
    return $this->hasMany('Relation5','id_table1','id_table1');
  }
  public function relation4s(){
    return $this->hasMany('Relation4','id_table1','id_table1');
  }
  public function relation3s(){
    return $this->hasMany('Relation3','id_table1','id_table1');
  }
  public function relation2s(){
    return $this->hasMany('Relation2','id_table1','id_table1');
  }
  public function relation1s(){
    return $this->hasMany('Relation1','id_table1','id_table1');
  }

}
```

This table is related to 5 tables names relation_table1,relation_table2 ... and so on.

Here is a sample model code for relation tables

```
 <?php

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations;
class Relation1 extends \Eloquent {
  public $timestamps = false;
  protected $table = 'relation_table1';
  protected $fillable = [ 'id_table1','idReseller', 'login', 'password', 'type','etc'];


  public function childs(){

        return $this->hasMany('Relation2','id_relation','id');

  }
  public function table1(){

        return $this->belongsTo('Table1','id_table1','id_table1');
  }
  public function scopeActive($query){
    return $query->whereRaw('type % 2 = 1');
  }
  public function scopeInactive($query){
    return $query->whereRaw('type % 2 = 0');
  }   
}
```

`
Problem is when i query below

```
$level=1; // i am controlling 5 relation tables in same controller via $level from route
$class = "Relation".$level;
     $collection  = new $class;    
$results = $collection->with('Table1')->orderBy($sort,$order)->paginate();
```

its working showing all result from relation table .. but its doesn't solve n+1 query problem. i mean for every row from relation1 its querying each time on table1 .. any idea how i can solve this ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is correct, just replace "Table1" by "table1":

```php
$results = $collection->with('table1')->orderBy($sort,$order)->paginate();
```

Comment: also `result->table1` not `result->Table1` (in your `foreach`)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading), you are using it with the **with** method so it will load them in the first query

```
$level=5
$class = "Relation".$level::with('Table1')->orderBy($sort,$order)->paginate();
```